# Match strings by row but ignore character order or special characters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have an output like this:

```
library(dplyr)  

Data <- tibble(
      Name1 = c("PlaceA, PlaceB & PlaceC", "PlaceD and PlaceE", "PlaceF.", "PlaceG & PlaceH", "Place K-Place L", "Place M and Place N","PlaceP-PlaceQ"),
      Name2 = c("PlaceB, PlaceA & PlaceC", "PlaceD & PlaceE", "PlaceF","PlaceG & PlaceJ", "Place L-Place K", "Place N and Place M","PlaceP-PlaceR"))
```

I would like to compare the two columns row by row to see if they are the same, but 1) ignore the order of the words 2) the characters used to separate the words and 3) if an '&' has been used instead of 'and'

With an output like this:

```
Data %>% mutate(Match = c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))
```

I'm sure there must be a way of using `stringr` to do this, but I can't find it.

**Edit**
@akrun noticing I had made a typo in my dummy data made me think about typos in my real data. If there is only one letter difference (either an additional letter or a mistyped letter in the word) then they are probably the same and should match. If a word has the same letters but in a different order it shouldn't. Something like this:

```
Mispellings <- tibble(
      Name1 = c("Location","Place","Racecar"),
      Name2 = c("Locatione","Pluce","Carrace"),
      Match = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Can any solution for my original question also deal with this additional scenario?

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: I think the edited part is very different from your original case because this may require distance methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split into list and `sort`, then do the comparison of list elements

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(Data$Name1, "\\s*[,&.-]\\s*|\\s*and\\s*"), sort)
lst2 <- lapply(strsplit(Data$Name2, "\\s*[,&.-]\\s*|\\s*and\\s*"), sort)
mapply(function(x, y) all(x == y), lst1, lst2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or use `setequal`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = setequal, unname(lapply(Data, 
    function(x) strsplit(x, "\\s*[,&.-]\\s*|\\s*and\\s*")))))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```